# knex query with quotes around table name

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a query as below which return user information where code is not null

> select name,age from "dev.user" where code is not null

return expected output

in knex I am doing

> knex("user").select('name','age').whereNotNull('code')

It return empty !

debug query return as follow

> select "name", "age" from "user" where "code" is not null
>   knex("dev.user").select('name','age').whereNotNull('code')

debug query return as follow

> select "name", "age" from "dev"."user" where "code" is not null

First when I initialise knex I have set the schema which is not working second even if I provide schema it is generating query as "dev"."user" instead of "dev.user"

any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?  I have views named like "a.b" and knex will generate 'a'.'b' instead of 'a.b'.

Comment: @EricRicher I remember using knew.raw function with table name gets generated based on env app is running on. I am sure this sud have some graceful solution now...

Comment: No graceful solution that I could find in the current version.  Ended up renaming the view to "a_b".  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks like you should use `.withSchema()`. ([see link](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-identifier-syntax))

> NOTE: identifier syntax has no place for selecting schema, so if you
>   are doing schemaName.tableName, query might be rendered wrong. Use
>   .withSchema('schemaName') instead.

Which would be:

```
knex("user")
   .withSchema("dev")
   .select('name','age').whereNotNull('code')
```

I haven't had to include a schema myself, so best of luck with this.

Gary.